# Toilet will not flush and has Air Bubbles

Tags: plumbing, bathroom

Toilet will not drain when flushed.  If I use a plunger for 5 min I can get the water to drain to normal level in the bowl.  If I turn on the water to the bathtub and sink both sandwiching the toilet air bubbles begin coming up in the bowl.  There are two other full baths in the home working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Will the bath keep draining? It sounds like the pipe below the toilet,sink & tub are plugged. The other bathrooms are probably closer to the tank / city sewer so they work fine. A [snake would probably clear the drain](https://www.zoro.com/ridgid-drain-cleaner-14-in-x-25-ft-cable-43148/i/G0345646/?gclid=CM3hmtCl9swCFUWTfgodq3AEhA&gclsrc=aw.ds). I would go in at the sink trap as these are easy to remove unless there is a clean out close by.